# Need to edit the XML file using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have XML content which I need to remove whole line from a particular element from a node.

XML File:

## need remove  whole line.

```
  <Host name="login.net">
    <Path name="Block">
      <Path name="webservices/login" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" />
      <Path name="login" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" />
      <Path name="weblogin" requireSession="true" authType="shibboleth" />
    </Path>
    <Path name="retailpdf" applicationId="retailpdf" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="retailpdf" />
    <Path name="managemyaccount" applicationId="managemyaccount" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="managemyaccount" />
    <Path name="approve" applicationId="approve" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="approve" />
    <Path name="latesignin" applicationId="latesignin" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="latesignin" />
    <Path name="fblogin" applicationId="fblogin" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="fblogin" />
  </Host>

</RequestMap>
```

# need to remove complete node of id retailpdf

Tried to remove the lines through powershell script

```
$XMLfilepath = 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml' 
psedit $XMLfilepath
$Pathxml = [xml] (Get-Content $XMLfilepath)

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/RequestMapper/Path");

{Remove-Item "<Path name="fblogin" applicationId="fblogin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="fblogin" />"}

$XMLfilepathNew = 'C:\Test\Myfiledone.xml' 
$Pathxml.Save($XMLfilepathNew)
psedit $XMLfilepathNew
```

Need to remove mentioned line and node in XML content like below:

Expected output:

```
  <Host name="login.net">
    <Path name="Block">
      <Path name="webservices/login" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" />
      <Path name="login" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" />
      <Path name="weblogin" requireSession="true" authType="shibboleth" />
    </Path>

    <Path name="managemyaccount" applicationId="managemyaccount" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="managemyaccount" />
    <Path name="approve" applicationId="approve" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="approve" />
    <Path name="latesignin" applicationId="latesignin" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="latesignin" />
    <Path name="fblogin" applicationId="fblogin" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="fblogin" />
  </Host>

</RequestMap>
```

```
 <ApplicationOverride id="retailpdf" entityID="https://login.tcxqa.hrblock.net/retailpdf/shibboleth">
  <Sessions lifetime="60" timeout="20" checkAddress="false" consistentAddress="false" handlerURL="/retailpdf/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="true">
    <SessionInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/retailpdf" isDefault="false" id="retailpdf" forceAuthn="true" entityID="https://qaidp.hrblock.net/idp/shibboleth" authnContextClassRef="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport">
      <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" template="bindingTemplate.html" />
    </SessionInitiator>
  </Sessions>
```

Comment: # need remove <Path name="retailpdf" applicationId="retailpdf" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="retailpdf" /> whole line.

Comment: # need to remove complete node of id retailpdf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$original = Get-Content 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml'
$new = $original.replace('<Path name="retailpdf" applicationId="retailpdf" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="retailpdf" />', '')
$new | Set-Content 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml'
```

Comment: Great This is working !! thank you so much @Panomosh

Comment: at the same time need to remove the whole need because attribute name = retailpdf also this node is related with same. will it possible to remove above node like you suggested.

Comment: Just edit the first argument of the `$original.replace()` method to match your node

Comment: No Thats not working as expected .  <ApplicationOverride id="retailpdf"     ##########################</ApplicationOverride> this my node , I need to remove whole this node. as you suggested i have updated the $original.replace() but there is no changes in output..

Comment: $original = Get-Content 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml'
#$new = $original.replace('<Path name="fblogin" applicationId="fblogin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="fblogin" />', '')
$new = $original.replace('<ApplicationOverride id="retailpdf" ######">
      <Sessions lifetime=###########>
       <SessionInitiator type=################ entityID="https://######" authnContextClassRef="ProtectedTransport">
          <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" />
        </SessionInitiator>
      </Sessions></ApplicationOverride>', ' ')
$new | Set-Content 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml'

Comment: `#$new = $original.rep` delete the hash its breaking the command

Comment: $original = Get-Content 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml' $new = $original.replace('<Path name="fblogin" applicationId="fblogin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="fblogin" />', '') $new = $original.replace('<ApplicationOverride id="retailpdf" ######"> <Sessions lifetime=###########> <SessionInitiator type=################ entityID="https://######" authnContextClassRef="ProtectedTransport"> <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" /> </SessionInitiator> </Sessions></ApplicationOverride>', ' ') $new | Set-Content 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml' –

Comment: Panomosh - i tried like above after removing # but still not out able find expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an XML file that is not broken, then you should be able to just remove the unwanted nodes using methods from the XmlDocument class.

```
$XMLfilepath = 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml' 
$Pathxml = [xml](Get-Content $XMLfilepath)
$nodeToRemove = $Pathxml.SelectSingleNode("//Host/Path[@name = 'retailpdf']")
$nodeToRemove.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove)
$nodeToRemove = $Pathxml.SelectSingleNode("//ApplicationOverride[@id = 'retailpdf']")
$nodeToRemove.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove)
$XMLfilepathNew = 'C:\Test\Myfiledone.xml' 
$Pathxml.Save($XMLfilepathNew)
```

Note that you can use wildcards in your XPaths. That would help in removing all attributes that contain specific values more concisely. However, you do need to understand the context levels of your XML data.

Comment: while using this getting some error like You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $Pathxml.SelectSingleNode('//RequestMapper/RequestMap/Host/Path[@name ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull ....do you have any points on this thanks in advance..

Comment: This is script.                                                                                         
$XMLfilepath = 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml' 
$Pathxml = [xml] (Get-Content $XMLfilepath)

$Pathxml.SelectSingleNode('//RequestMapper/RequestMap/Host/Path[@name = "retailpdf"]').RemoveAll() 

$Pathxml.SelectSingleNode("//SPConfig/ApplicationOverride[@id = 'retailpdf']").RemoveAll() 



$XMLfilepathNew = 'C:\Test\shibboleth.xml' 
$Pathxml.Save($XMLfilepathNew)

Comment: The main part that is missing is the xml structure. It’s hard to do a Xpath with no accurate xml data

Comment: Thank You for that, may i know the change , i couldn't able to find exact change.

Comment: I changed the XPath in the second `SelectSingleNode()` from `"//RequestMap/ApplicationOverride[@id = 'retailpdf']"`.

Comment: Yeah tried that also, but  it giving same response like  
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $Pathxml.SelectSingleNode("//RequestMap/ApplicationOverride[@id = 're ...

Comment: The XML in the screenshot is missing the closing `>` on the beginning `<SPConfig` tag.

Comment: Are namespaces used at all in your ***actual*** XML?

Comment: because after that there is attribute declaration ..thats y

Comment: Yeah..its actual XML

Comment: I made a code change that will wipe out the lines you want entirely instead of just deleting the contents of the node. However, I don't think it will fix your problem. When you run the new code, does `$nodeToRemove` have anything in it?

Comment: this return the same error.
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:1+ $nodeToRemove.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nodeToRemove)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: but this one working very well. no trouble to remove that one perticular line. $original = Get-Content 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml'
$new = $original.replace('<Path name="retailpdf" applicationId="retailpdf" authType="qwerty" requireSession="true" requireSessionWith="retailpdf" />', '')
$new | Set-Content 'C:\Test\MYfile.xml'

Comment: There is some key data missing from your XML post then. I created an XML file based on your screenshot, and this code works without issues on PowerShell 5.1. I did, however, fix all the broken things about the XML you posted, which includes not properly closed tags.

Comment: Okay >> thank you so much for the instructions ..let me try to fix it..